# Passing Parameters from one VF Page to a Controller used by another VF Page using CommandLink

Tags: visualforce, commandlink

Let me 1st start by saying, I have looked all over the net for an answer, could not gt it done.  Thought it would be simple. But is not working.

**Problem:**  RoomType variable is not getting set.  It is coming in as NULL, which I am passing to my SOQL as a parameter.

Where am I going wrong ?  ANy better ideas to resolve this matter?

TIA

**Page 1**

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Transactions__c.Room_Type__c}" label="Room Type" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Transactions__c.Transaction_Type__c}" label="Transaction Type"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Transactions__c.Check_In_Date__c}" label="CheckIn Date"/>

<apex:commandlink id="CLink" value="Check Availability" onclick="window.open('https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/GetAvailableRooms','_blank','height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)" style="background:#99CCFF; font-weight=bold" >
                         <apex:param name="RoomType" value="{!Transactions__c.Room_Type__c}"/> </apex:commandlink>
```

In short the Command Link "Check Availability" is opening up another page GetAvailableRooms using windows.open

**Page:  GetAvailableRooms**

```
<apex:page controller="getAvailableRooms" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AvailableRooms}" var="AR">
            <apex:column value="{!AR.Date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!AR.Room_Type__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!AR.Room_Number__c}"/>

            <apex:column value="{!AR.Room_Status__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller: getAvailableRooms

```
public class getAvailableRooms{
    // ApexPages.StandardSetController must be instantiated
    // for standard list controllers
    public String RoomType {get; set;}



    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {


                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Room_Type__c, Room_Number__c, Room_Status__c, Date__c  FROM Room_Availabiity__c
                    WHERE Date__c >= TODAY AND Room_Type__c = :RoomType
                    //AND Room_Type__c = :RoomType
                    ORDER BY Date__c ASC, Room_Type__c ASC]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Room_Availabiity__c> getAvailableRooms() {
       RoomType = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RoomType');
       System.debug(RoomType); 

        return (List<Room_Availabiity__c>) setCon.getRecords();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the value in the URL itself

```
<apex:commandlink id="CLink" value="Check Availability" onclick="window.open('https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/GetAvailableRooms?RoomType="{!Transactions__c.Room_Type__c}"','_blank','height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)" style="background:#99CCFF; font-weight=bold" >
```

Also since you are passing from one page to other its better to pass as URL as encoded string and then url decode at other end

Comment: Mohit

Between the time I posted the question and you posted the reply, I tried what you mentioned.
Unfortunately, the commandLink does not work the 1st time I lick. RoomType is passed as blank.  Strangely enough when I click on the Link 2nd time, it does get passed.  Not sure why.

Also since the inputField is a Lookup Field it is passing the RoomType ID, which is still fine by me.  

But the bigger question is why does the value not get passed when I click the 1st time.

I did not think, this would be such a big hassle.  
Any other ideas?  Any other way of doing this ?

Comment: use href of html  instead .But it is strange that it does not work on first time ..